# Woocommerce Cart Showing Duplicate Cart Totals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website running woocommerce and on the cart page it's showing 2 cart totals at the checkout. I'm not seeing where anyone has even posted about this anywhere so it seems really random. Any ideas?

My quick fix was to just hide the second one using css.

Comment: Is one of the cart totals labeled "Subtotal"? There's a subtotal and total row by default

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function call in the template got removed, added back via an action. Every theme overwriting this template will still have the original function call, as well as the function added via the action. This shouldn't be pushed in a fix release like this, in my humble opinion. But now it's there, let's resolve this.
Resolving the issue

Resolving this issue is actually fairly easy. Your theme will have the cart/cart.php overwritten in the woocommerce folder of your (child) theme. In there, you will find this line (or at least something similar calling that same function):

```
<?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>
```

You need to remove this line from your overwritten template file and your cart totals should only appear once.

Comment: Many thanks, suddenly noticed this on my site. Might have at least had a warning of some sort!

Comment: Same problem, and this solution corrected it, but I now also have two sections where credit card info is entered. I believe it has something to do with the `review-order.php` template file, but can't narrow it down. Any suggestions on that one?

Comment: Even after commentig out the quantity is adding in twice please help.

Answer (score 1):

Although not the cleanest, here's an alternative solution **if you don't have a child theme and/or you don't want to modify your PHP files:**

Find the CSS selector of your cart totals. In my case, it was `div.cart_totals.calculated_shipping.wow.fadeInLeft.animated`

And use an `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-selector like so:

```
div.cart_totals.calculated_shipping.wow.fadeInLeft.animated:nth-of-type(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

That'll make sure if there's a second cart totals div then it won't display.